# load pinterest script when needed

Tags: pinterest

I have an index page where Pinterest button will be visible many times for different items.
I want to be sure that page loads fast and Pinterest buttons do not slow down the page.

How ever, since pinterest JS parses DOM and replaces code in pinit button, this will become expensive for me if number of buttons are high.

Can I somehow improve this process. How I can call a pinterest script only when needed ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what we recommend for site operators who want to load the Pinterest script asynchronously:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d){
  var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0], p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
  p.type = 'text/javascript';
  p.async = true;
  p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
}(document));
</script>
```

This should not block loading of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various options and approaches:

1. Dynamically loading file using $.getScript method.
2. Live event binding using $.live method.
3. Not loading PINTEREST script and handling popup on click using javascript.

3rd approach works best for me. It gives me control of popup positioning and also does not invoke any unnecessary calls to Pinterest script.